# Argument must be str not bytes

Tags: python, unicode, ansible

I'm running Ansible 2.2.0.0 from Travis-CI in order to install a common shared version of Terraform that we are using in our project.

I can run it locally without issues, but when I run it in Travis, it seems to fail on some encoding of a string sourced from a variable:

```
[WARNING]: Host file not found: /etc/ansible/hosts

[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [terraform : create terraform directory] **********************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [terraform : install terraform] *******************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Failure downloading https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.7.13/terraform_0.7.13_linux_amd64.zip, write() argument must be str, not bytes"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Host Ansible and Python versions:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-14:/vagrant/ansible$ python3 --version
Python 3.4.3
vagrant@ubuntu-14:/vagrant/ansible$ ansible --version
ansible 2.2.0.0
  config file = /vagrant/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

Travis Ansible and Python versions:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.4.2
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.2.0.0
  config file = 
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

I have validated that `LANG` is `en_US.UTF-8` in both places.

Here is my playbook:

```
---
  - hosts: localhost
    roles:
      - role: terraform
        terraform_install_root: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/terraform/"
        bin_dir: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.local/bin"
```

Here is `roles/terraform/tasks/main.yml`:

```
---
 - name: create terraform directory
   file: path={{ terraform_install_root }}/{{ terraform_version }} state=directory

 - name: install terraform
   unarchive:
     copy: no
     src: "https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/{{ terraform_version }}/terraform_{{ terraform_version }}_linux_amd64.zip"
     dest: "{{ terraform_install_root }}/{{ terraform_version }}"
     creates: "{{ terraform_install_root }}/{{ terraform_version }}/terraform"

 - name: ensure bin directory exists
   file: path={{ bin_dir }} state=directory

 - name: create terraform symlink
   file: src={{ terraform_install_root }}/{{ terraform_version }}/terraform dest={{ bin_dir }}/terraform state=link
```

Here is `roles/terraform/vars/main.yml`:

```
---
terraform_version: "0.7.13"
terraform_install_root: /opt/terraform/
bin_dir: /usr/local/bin
```

It appears that for some reason, Ansible is failing to convert something into UTF-8, even though I'm not doing anything strange, and what runs locally just fine does *not* run on Travis.

Furthermore, it appears that there are no non-ASCII characters in any of these files:

```
$ file -i ansible/roles/terraform/tasks/main.yml
ansible/roles/terraform/tasks/main.yml: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
$ file -i ansible/roles/terraform/vars/main.yml
ansible/roles/terraform/vars/main.yml: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
$ file -i ansible/travis-playbook.yml
ansible/travis-playbook.yml: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The error message is the *opposite* of what you claim, the string must be a Unicode string and not UTF-8 encoded bytes.

Comment: @MarkRansom I have updated the ticket, there are no non-ASCII characters in any of the files.

Comment: Non-ASCII shouldn't matter. Something somewhere is missing a decode or putting in an extra encode.

Answer (score 0):

Use the quotes around `src` of this task:

```
 - name: install terraform
   unarchive:
     copy: no
     src: "https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/{{ terraform_version }}/terraform_{{ terraform_version }}_linux_amd64.zip"
     dest: "{{ terraform_install_root }}/{{ terraform_version }}"
     creates: "{{ terraform_install_root }}/{{ terraform_version }}/terraform"
```

Then run it:

```
ansible-playbook -i 192.168.33.33, terraform.yml                                                               2 ↵

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [192.168.33.33]

TASK [terraform-stackoverflow : create terraform directory] ********************
ok: [192.168.33.33]

TASK [terraform-stackoverflow : install terraform] *****************************
changed: [192.168.33.33]

TASK [terraform-stackoverflow : ensure bin directory exists] *******************
changed: [192.168.33.33]

TASK [terraform-stackoverflow : create terraform symlink] **********************
changed: [192.168.33.33]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.33.33              : ok=5    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: I am using it with python2.7, can you check that

Comment: I need at least Python 3.4. I have attempted with Python 3.4 and 3.5 and see both fail.

Answer (score 0):

As much of a cop-out as this is, I updated to use Travis' `trusty` (Ubuntu 14.04) image beta and the problem went away.

It should be noted that `precise` is Ubuntu 12.04, which is four, coming on five years old.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known Ansible bug ([#5791](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/5791)) and has been fixed in `develop`, although it is not in a release yet ([commit ansible/ansible@1963e50](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/1963e506ecdef1ab14de1b634d02c0214399bbea)).

Perhaps you can install a separate 2.7 Python on the target host just for the use of Ansible? (You can configure the interpreter to use with `ansible_python_interpreter` in the [inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters).) I found trying to use Python3 with Ansible is a never-ending game of whack-a-bug, although in all fairness the Ansible is actively working on fixing that.